# Sbrk and negative parameter

Tags: c, malloc, sbrk

I am running into a problem when i am freeing memory using sbrk. I pass sbrk a negative value but it doesnt decrement the start of the heap. Here is the code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void * a = sbrk(0);
    printf("%p\n",a);

    sbrk(2);
    sbrk(-1);
    a = sbrk(0);
    printf("%p\n",a);
}
```

And here is sample output:

0x10734f000

0x10734f002

I don't understand why the printed value isn't coming back as 0x10734f001 after sbrk is decremented by one.

I am not allowed to use malloc in this program. This is for a custom implementation of malloc and free using sbrk

Comment: Check the return value of your `sbrk(-1)`... Perhaps you aren't allowed to do that...

Comment: the return value is the same as the value for sbrk(0). is there another way to decrement the sbrk value then?

Comment: What OS/hardware/etc.? brk is very platform specific. (works as you intend it to on my linux/amd64)

Comment: @keltar im writing it in netbeans 7 on mac os x and compiling with 32 bit architecture

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/emulated/brk.c I'm not sure it is actual code for i386 (or whatever), but behaviour you're experiencing fits into it quite well.

Comment: thats so weird. bit of an annoyance :/

Comment: Is it required to use `sbrk`? If not, i'd rather stick to `mmap` as it is just much more predictable and don't suffer fragmentation

Comment: @keltar yes i believe we have to use sbrk :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested it with MacOSX Mavericks and sbrk() behaves (nearly) the same than on Linux with two exceptions:

- I get a compiler warning:
  `tst21.c:12:6: warning: 'sbrk' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]`
- it doesn't seem to be possible to give back memory to the OS using a negative value (this is - as far as I remember - the same behaviour observed on SYSV4 decades ago: releasing memory allocated by `sbrk()` wasn't possible)

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the sizes you use are too small, so that there is some form of rounding happening inside `sbrk()`. I would never expect byte-level precision for something like this, it's more likely to work in units of pages (which are 4 KB or thereabouts on typical Linux systems).

Also, note that the manual says:

> Avoid using brk() and sbrk(): the malloc(3) memory allocation package is the portable and comfortable way of allocating memory.

It's likely that `malloc()` knows about any limitations `sbrk()` has and handles them, it's the preferred application-level interface.

Comment: i've seen it in a lot of places. here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051994/how-do-i-free-memory-obtained-by-sbrk

Comment: @cthemc Thanks! I also failed to see the mention of negative increment that the manual page had. I've edited.

Comment: i have to write my own malloc for a school project. the prompt suggests using a negative parameter so im not sure why what i have is not working >_<

Comment: Which platform are you on? Your example works for me (Linux), no matter how large increment/decrement pairs are.
Did you notice that `sbrk()` doesn't return the new but the previous `brk`?

Comment: @mfro im on mac os x compiling with a 32 bit architecture

Comment: OS/X and Linux `sbrk()`should do the same thing, according to the manpages. Linux says "`sbrk()` returns the previous program break" while the MaxOSX manpage says "`sbrk()` returns the base of the new storage" which sounds completely different but is essentially the same thing.
It may sound weird, but `sbrk(0)` and `sbrk(1000)` actually return the same (correct) value - the previous program break.

Answer (score 1):

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void *a = sbrk(0);
  printf("%p\n", a);

  a = sbrk(2);
  printf("%p\n", a);

  a = sbrk(-1);
  printf("%p\n", a);

  a = sbrk(0);
  printf("%p\n", a);
}
```

Output:

```
0x560267a31000
0x560267a52000
0x560267a52002
0x560267a52001
```

According to [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html)
`void *sbrk(intptr_t increment)` return **old value of brk** when success. sbrk(0) return current brk.

Answer (score -1):

printf uses malloc and thereby increases the data segment size

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `printf` doesn't use malloc. It just converts data on the fly and outputs it to standard output.

Answer (score -1):

Try it out without using printf and print out your results by using a debugger. It will work fine and the result will be as expected. The heap will get incremented by 2 and decremented by -1, as intended.