# How to throw an error when a program acesses a block of memory created by you that has been deallocated by a call of free?

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, heap-memory

excuse my English, I'm actually Spanish. It has been an hour since I'm trying to solve a problem which it seems it has no solutions. I'm trying to implement malloc and free. This is the code which I've written so far:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct block_on_free {
    int size;
    struct block_on_free *previous;
    struct block_on_free *next;
    void *data;
} block_on_free;

block_on_free *phead = NULL;

size_t icf_malloc (size_t size) {

    for (block_on_free *current = phead; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        if (current->size >= size) {
            if (current->previous == NULL) 
                phead = current->next;
            else 
                current->previous->next = current->next;
            
            return current;
        }
    }

    // No compatible block on free list
    block_on_free *new = sbrk (size + sizeof (block_on_free));
    new->size = size + sizeof (block_on_free);
    new->next = NULL;
    new->previous = NULL;
    new->data = (void *) (char *) new + sizeof (block_on_free);
    return new->data;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to implement free, however, I'm wondering how could I deallocate memory from the heap and if someone attempts to tamper with the deallocated block of memory throw a **SEGMENTATION FAULT** right away as it would happen if we use the free library function

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may be interested by this thread, if you want to release some allocated memory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666728/
Also, I don't think you have to throw a segfault by yourself if something access memory it shouldn't, it should already be handled by the kernel.

Comment: "....  if someone attempts to tamper with the deallocated block of memory throw a SEGMENTATION FAULT right away **as it would happen if we use the free library function**" You can't be sure that you will get a segfault when accessing memory after calling `free`. Maybe you will, maybe you wont

Comment: It looks like you have a linked-list of pointers into memory allocated by moving the `brk`. When you move the brk you grow the size of the heap available. You still have to keep track of the blocks, even if you free them. To catch the use after free, rather than doing whatever you are doing with the `block_on_free` typedef, why not add a simple `bool` or `int` to your struct to indicate if that node has been freed. Then you can iterate over the nodes in your allocated list and if action is taken on one that has that member indicating it has been freed - then you can handle the error.